# If Google BigQuery returns an error, am I paying for using the resources?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, cloud

I'm using a CROSS JOIN across 2 tables in Google BigQuery. Then the following error appears

```
Resources exceeded during query execution: Your project or organization exceeded the maximum disk and memory limit available for shuffle operations. Consider provisioning more slots, reducing query concurrency, or using more efficient logic in this job.
```

Is this kind of query being charged by Google?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing) section "On-demand pricing" I would say, that you should not be charged for queries that return an error.

> You aren't charged for queries that return an error or for queries that retrieve results from the cache.